# Upgrading Python On Mac OS with Anaconda On Machine

Tags: python, macos

I'm on the edge with this one. Just went through this [how-to-article](https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac) on upgrading python on your mac (I'm on the latest upgrade-10.15.3-Catalina) with homebrew (it's option three in the article). It went well, and my system (finally) seemed to recognize that we are well beyond 2.7 and now defaults to 3.8. I then went to set up a virtual env for a project. I installed the `googleapiclient` in the folder and got a deprecation warning stating I was using python 2.7! I then ran python -V inside the virtual environment and, lo' and behold, it says it's running Python 2.7.16. What is going on???

Of note, I have anaconda on my system. I'm not doing this project in anaconda because it just threw a `conda command not found` error, though the command was there last week, so we are not on speaking terms at the moment.

Comment: Make sure you upgrade python in your virtualenv.  Because in your virtualenv python has not been updated. Only in your main system did python upgrade. Alternatively, you can clone the env with python3.

Comment: How could my venv possibly have python at all, if it did not pull it from the global environment, which is now using Python3?

Comment: You might still be using python2 when you create your virtualenv. Haven't checked your article but you can specific which python version your virtualenv can using with the `-p` argument, i.e. `virtualenv -p python3 .venv`.

Comment: How did you "set up" a virtual env?